# Suddenly Angular's Chrome Debugger extension is acting weird in visual studio code

Tags: angularjs, typescript, debugging, google-chrome-extension

Since a couple of days ago, I can't properly debug any of my projects using Angular's Chrome Debugger extension in Visual Studio Code. If I set a breakpoint at one line of code, it breaks in a completely different line and also, I have to refresh the page the first time for it to work!

Here are the versions I'm working with:

> Angular CLI Version : 1.7.4
>   Visual Studio Version: 1.22.1

This is my `launch.json`, and it was working all these months with this configuration, the only thing I recall that changed was an update in Visual Studio Code from 1.21 to 1.22, but I rolled back to 1.21 and still the problem is there, has someone experienced those issues?

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "url": "http://localhost:4200",
          "sourceMaps": true,
          "trace": true,
          "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
          "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/chrome",
          "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
              "webpack:///*":"/*"
          }
    },
    {
      "name": "Attach to Chrome, with sourcemaps",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9222,
      "sourceMaps": true,
      /*"diagnosticLogging": true,*/
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/*",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
          "webpack:///*": "/*"
      }
  }      
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try Chrome Canary or an older portable Chrome - maybe it's a bug in the browser.